Reduce expiry time for Azure Managed Identity
Need a way to generate an Azure Managed Identity token with shorter expiry time. Today I am using the following curl command to fetch my Managed Identity token . This token is valid for 24 hrs by default.
/usr/bin/curl --noproxy '*' --connect-timeout 3 'http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https://storage.azure.com/' -H 'Metadata:true'

Is there a way to generate a token with 10min expiry? can we pass an input to the above curl to do the same ? or what other options doe we have?

As per documentation, this is not supported.
Configurable token lifetimes in the Microsoft identity platform

You can specify the lifetime of an access, ID, or SAML token issued by the Microsoft identity platform. You can set token lifetimes for all apps in your organization, for multitenant (multi-organization) applications, or for service principals. We currently don't support configuring the token lifetimes for managed identity service principals.

